# Event listener for dataLayer push events on Tag Manager JS

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I want to add a custom script that integrates into an existing Tag Manager dataLayer on a page. I need this script to be notified about new dataLayer pushes.
So whenever something on the page uses `window.dataLayer.push`, my script should be informed about this.

Is there a way to add a custom dataLayer event listener to the Google Script API?

I am looking for something like

```
google_tag_manager.dataLayer.onPush(callback);
```

`google_tag_manager.dataLayer.subscribers` seems to list how many dataLayer subscribers there are - but how can I add my own?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JavaScript has a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object with which you can set *traps* whenever an operation is executed on an object. Arrays are also objects and can be used with proxies.

When calling the `push` method on an array, a new value will be `set` to the array. So setting a trap for the `set` method should allow us to add behavior to the `push` method.

In the trap, create a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) event and dispatch it. You can name this event anything you want. Whenever a value has been added to the `dataLayer` array, an event will be emitted. You can listen from every file to this event to act on whenever a value is added to the `dataLayer` array.

With [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) we can make sure that the original behavior of the `push` method is restored while keeping the added behavior.

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || new Proxy([], {
  set: (obj, prop, value) => {  
    if (prop !== 'length') {
      const pushEvent = new CustomEvent('datalayerpush', {
        detail: value
      });

      window.dispatchEvent(pushEvent);
    }
    
    return Reflect.set(obj, prop, value);
  }
});

window.addEventListener('datalayerpush', event => {
  console.log(`Value pushed to dataLayer: ${JSON.stringify(event.detail, null, 2)}`);
});

window.dataLayer.push({
  event: 'test'
});
```

Comment: Just in case this snippet isn't placed in the global scope it may be safer to assign to `window.dataLayer` instead of `var dataLayer` to be explicit that it replaces the reference to the existing dataLayer for that global variable.

Comment: Keep in mind this does not work with IE11, but who cares about dead Browsers ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can do a 'native' implementation using the google_tag_manager object. You can, however, override the push method on the dataLayer array.

```js
const originalPush = dataLayer.push
dataLayer.push = function(...args) {
    // notify here
    console.log('dataLayer.push was called');
    
    originalPush(...args);
}
```

You can then implement some logic based on the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Below I show a VERY simple implementation, just for demonstration.

```js
const originalPush = dataLayer.push
const dataLayerListeners = [];
dataLayer.push = function(...args) {
    dataLayerListeners.forEach(listener => listener.notify())
    
    originalPush(...args);
}

class DatalayerListener {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    notify(args) {
        console.log("I'm listener "+this.name+" and I'm being notified that the dataLayer.push method was called");
    }
}

const listener1 = new DatalayerListener('listener1');
const listener2 = new DatalayerListener('listener2');

dataLayerListeners.push(listener1);
dataLayerListeners.push(listener2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same requirement, but I also wasn't allowed to directly modify the `dataLayer` definition so couldn't use a Proxy. Happily Google have created a library that provides a set of helper functions tailored to the object: https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper

Deploy the script, then create a callback listener:

```
function listener(model, message) {
  // Message has been pushed. 
  // The helper has merged it onto the model.
  // Now use the message and the updated model to do something.
}
```

The added bonus here is you can use "listenToPast" to replay all events that were added to the `dataLayer` before the code ran (also a requirement in my case).

```
const helper = new DataLayerHelper(dataLayer, {
  listener: listener,
  listenToPast: true,
});
```